# Как получить целочисленные значения из массива mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Записал в в одно поле mysql три числа(21,22,23).
Через цикл хочу проверить, совпадает ли число из данного поля базы данных с некоторым числом. У меня не получилось. Когда проверяю через gettype показывает (string NULL NULL).

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT dostup FROM users where id='$id'",$db);
$re=mysql_fetch_array($res);

for($i=0;$i<=count($re);$i++){
    echo gettype($re[$i]);
};
```

когда через echo показываю, все числа нормально выводятся. Но условие if выполняется только для первого(21) числа. 
В базе данных записаны через запятую. Объявлены как varchar(пробовал int, тоже самое).

Когда хочу принудительно объявить как целое число, уходит в бесконечный цикл(integerintegerintegerinteger...и т.д).

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT dostup FROM users where id='$id'",$db);
$re=mysql_fetch_array($res);

for($i=0;$i<=count($re);$i++){
    settype($re[$i],"integer");
    echo gettype($re[$i]);
};
```

Вот как я хотел сделать.

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT dostup FROM users where id='$id'",$db);
$re=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$chislo=22;

for($i=0;$i<=count($re);$i++){
    if($re[$i]==$chislo){
    echo "Есть совпадение";
break;
    }
};
```

Comment: Вам БД возвращает строку, в единственном элементе массива. count($re) всегда равен 1, поле то одно (и БД никак не может догадаться, что вы положили туда значение в котором надо считать запятые разделителем) ... Вам надо взять значение и разобрать его самостоятельно в массив, с помощью explode

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем понял. Можете подсказать ещё?                                                         
 $r = explode("  ","$re");
//var_dump($r);

for($i=0;$i<=count($r);$i++){
 
 echo gettype($r[$i]);
};

Comment: *Записал в в одно поле* Имя поля мы должны угадать? *совпадает ли число из данного поля базы данных с некоторым числом* Где находится это "некоторое число", мы должны в ХШ разглядеть? *условие if выполняется только для первого(21) числа* А если учесть, что в коде нет `if` - вообще уржаться. PS. Приведите этот апофеоз недоделок в приличное состояние. PPS. А заодно найдите и почитайте описание функции FIND_IN_SET().

Comment: Я это не написал, потому посчитал это не особо важным. Ведь главная проблема не в этом. А в том что из поля числа не выводятся как целочисленные.

Comment: Akina, добавил.

Comment: explode(",",$re[0]), ведь $re это все таки массив. И разбивать надо по запятой а не по пробелу

Comment: @АйратБайгильдин, у Вас запись в БД такая `21,22,23`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В том случае, если у Вас в БД данные записаны как `21,22,23'

> В базе данных записаны через запятую.

То надо сначала разбить результат на массив, а потом провести поиск по этому массиву, и так для каждой записи.

Пример:

```php
$res=mysql_query("SELECT dostup FROM users where id='$id'",$db);
$re=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$chislo=22;

for($i=0;$i<=count($re);$i++){
    $temp = explode(',', $re[$i]); //Разбиваем данные из строки БД

    foreach ($temp as $k=>$value){ //Проводим поиск по полученному массиву
        if($value==$chislo){
            echo "Есть совпадение";
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Для теста пример:

```php
$re = array('21,20,23', '24,25,26', '27,28,29'); // Аналог полученных данных в mysql, если их много. 

$chislo=22;

for($i=0;$i<=count($re);$i++){
    $temp = explode(',', $re[$i]);

    foreach ($temp as $k=>$value){
        if($value==$chislo){
            echo "Есть совпадение";
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я как раз таки сделал. Пока отправлял вы уже дали ответ :D

Comment: Но я принудительно менял строковый тип на численный через settype.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как я решил эту проблему.

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT dostup FROM users where id='$id'",$db);
$re=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$chislo=22;
$p = explode(",","$re[0]");
for($i=0;$i<count($p);$i++){
settype($p[$i],"integer");
if($p[$i]==$chislo){echo "есть совпадение";
}
}
```

Наверное ещё можно было бы через FIND_IN_SET, но я не стал копаться.